# Error when trying to connect to http://localhost:3000

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting this error when trying to connect to my local server. I have searched on several sites and have tried a few of the suggestions that were said to have worked.

I am running:

- Windows 10
- Ruby 2.3.3p222 `(2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]`
- Rails 5.0.2

The following is what I get when I open the server:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Sassy Salamander
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
```

The error comes back as the following:

```
Access denied for user 'rails_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Extracted source (around line #89):

87      socket = socket.to_s unless socket.nil?
88
89      connect user, pass, host, port, database, socket, flags
90    end
91
92    def parse_ssl_mode(mode).
```

Is there something incorrect based on the error log that I posted?

Comment: I did some googling and made an educated guess that the startup messages and the error message are two different things (with your own words in between), and that the line numbers should be aligned with the code. Please [edit] your question if I got something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Access denied for user 'rails_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
check you database.yml if the password of the database is correct